# Disable saving a form after manualy enter a date in datepicker in octoberCMS

Tags: forms, datepicker, save, octobercms

When I use a datepicker widget on a backend form and a user enters a date manualy the form is saved when pressing enter in that field; Is there any way to disable that behavior?

my yaml file

```
fields:
    field_1:
        label: field_1
        type: text
        span: storm
        cssClass: col-xs-4
        attributes:
            tabindex: 1
    field_2:
        label: field_2
        type: text
        span: storm
        cssClass: col-xs-4
        attributes:
            tabindex: 2
    date:
        label: 'date, don't press enter!'
        mode: date
        type: datepicker
        span: storm
        cssClass: col-xs-4
        attributes:
            tabindex: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do this in javascript.

You can include javascript a few ways- my preferred option is to define a partial in your fields.yaml and put the javascript in the partial. You could also directly include the javascript in the create.htm and/or update.htm files in `plugins/foo/bar/controllers/baz/`

Something like this would work:

```
$('form').on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode === 13) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Note that it is frowned upon to change the way that forms and keystrokes work- the default behavior of browsers, screen readers, etc., assume that hitting enter will submit the form. I suggest you only make this change if you have a small sample of users that you can pass this information to (or just tell them not to hit enter until they want to submit the form).